# входная строка имеет неверный формат(запуск формы)

Tags: c#

При запуске формы внезапно выскочила данная ошибка. В форме загружается дерево подразделений. Но других ошибок нет при отладке, на ошибки конвертации ничего не указывает. Отладка проходит до последнего шага, на котором возникает эта ошибка. Куда копать? Что глядеть? Пока что не понимаю и прошу помощи.

[image: Скриншот прилагаю]

Comment: Отключайте по одному инициализацию в конструкторе формы вплоть до появления формы.

Comment: При чем тут WPF?

Comment: @AzizUmarov проблема в том, что форма появляется, потом начинает загружаться дерево на теперешнюю дату и выскакивает это исключение